# Changes made to custom.scss file in bootstrap not working

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4, sass, laravel-mix

I have created a custom.scss file next to the scss file locatce within the bootstrap node module on my laravel server, the contents of the file are

```
/* custom.scss */    

/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_variables";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints";

/* make changes to the !default Bootstrap variables */    
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 600px,
  md: 800px,
  lg: 1000px,
  xl: 1280px
);

/* finally, import Bootstrap to set the changes! */
@import "~bootstrap";
```

what i am attempting to achieve is to change the bootstrap 4 breakpoints, but the breakpoints are still being loaded from _root.scss hwoever my app.css file which is generated from npm run dev is being shown as a file firefox can see but all of the options are greyed out and have a line through them.
Is there any way i can change this to use the grid breakpoints i have defined.
Thanks

Comment: Ditch your `custom.scss` and move your changes/modifications to Laravel's `app.scss`?! "_next to the scss file locatce within the bootstrap node module_" I wouldn't add/change anything in those "vendor" folders, if there's an update of Bootstrap chances are your file gets removed/deleted

Comment: Is there another copy/instance/reference to bootstrap.css included after the app.css?

Comment: all the tutorials i have seen for changing bootstraps breakpoints are in teh custom.scss file in the bootstrap node module, how would i get it to work in my app.scss file because i have tried this. Thanks

Comment: @Zim yes there is i have trioed swapping the order, its the bootstrap css file i have also included the js files

Comment: Can you just remove the other bootstrap.css file? It shouldn't be needed since you're importing it in your custom css

Comment: Just adding your custom breakpoints to `app.scss` _before_ the line `@import 'variables';` should do it. Works fine for me

Comment: @Zim yh i just spotted that, are the js files included as well and if so where are they included, in case i need to edit them later because up until now i thought i had to import them. Thank you

Comment: Quick question: did you use `laravel/ui` to load/include Bootstrap?

Comment: that didint work so i used laravel ui "^2.0"

Answer (score 1):

I find this question interesting because I didn't realise your method might actually work. How I normally handle bootstrap variable overrides is like this...

```
// make font sizes responsive
$enable-responsive-font-sizes: true;

// import bootstrap initial sass vendors
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// remove colors from bs color var maps
$grays: map-remove($grays, "100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800","900");
$theme-colors: map-remove($theme-colors, "primary","secondary","success","danger","warning","info","light","dark");
$colors: map-remove($colors, "blue","indigo","purple","pink","red","orange","yellow","green","teal","cyan","white","gray","gray-dark");

// @debug $colors;

// get my var overrides sass
@import "./vars";

// finish loading rest of bs sass lib with my var and color map changes applied
@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/navbar";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/badge";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/media";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/list-group";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/popover";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/carousel";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/spinners";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/print";
```

And overriding sass variables in `./vars` look like this...

```
/* grid breakpoints
-------------------------------------------------- */

$grid-breakpoints: (
  // Extra small screen / phone
  xs: 0,
  // Extra small screen / phone
  is: 350px,
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576px,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768px,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992px,
  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1200px
);
```

I always presumed `@import "~bootstrap";` after sass variable overrides would just re-import `bootstrap/scss/variables` again resetting all my custom variable overrides back to the default `bootstrap/scss/variables`.

I will look into your method to see if it actually works, however the method i've posted works if you are stuck.